# XNA 4.0 Problems regarding 3D sphere as a planet

Tags: xna

EDIT: I added a pastebin of most of the code. Since i cant add it to this post, those links can be found in comments.

Im playing around with XNA 4.0 Procedurally generated planets.

Problem 1:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PofhL.png

As you can see, there are visible triangles at edge of the planet. I tried so many things but I cant figure out how to get rid of this effect. The texture itself is fine and the sphere is an imported model.

ps. and yes, i have read about similar issues but none helped me resolve my issue.

Problem 2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV28k.png

This is what happens when I move away my camera. I did my research and I modified near plane, far plane and some other things. Nothing helped. Note: The clouds effect is not done by me and somehow it doesnt disappear.

I dont attach any code at this moment because I wouldnt be surprised if the answer is easy for somebody experienced. However, if needed i can paste the needed code here.

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I dont want planets to disappear ever. I want to be able to move camera far away and still see those planets even if they are just dots.

Ok i will prove more explanation. Im a begginer at XNA and programming in general. This is why it might be a bit hard to understand me :<
1. Sphere model is imported.

1. Textures are generated and stored. I was able to look at them as square texture files and they looked fine so they are not the problem.
2. This is where I dont understand some parts of code that i found on internet. I attached pieces of code that in my opinion could have an error. Also the commented out lines are not that relevant.

   private void UpdateCamera()
       {
           // Calculate the view matrix.

   ```
       Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Identity;
       float heading = MathHelper.ToRadians(camera.rotation.Y);
       float pitch = MathHelper.ToRadians(camera.rotation.X);

       if (heading != 0.0f)
       {
           rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, heading);
           Quaternion.Concatenate(ref rotation, ref camera.orientation, out camera.orientation);
       }

       if (pitch != 0.0f)
       {
           rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, pitch);
           Quaternion.Concatenate(ref camera.orientation, ref rotation, out camera.orientation);
       }

       Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(ref camera.orientation, out camera.viewMatrix);

       Vector3 xAxis = new Vector3(camera.viewMatrix.M11, camera.viewMatrix.M21, camera.viewMatrix.M31);
       Vector3 yAxis = new Vector3(camera.viewMatrix.M12, camera.viewMatrix.M22, camera.viewMatrix.M32);
       Vector3 zAxis = new Vector3(camera.viewMatrix.M13, camera.viewMatrix.M23, camera.viewMatrix.M33);

       camera.target -= xAxis * camera.translate.X;
       camera.target -= yAxis * camera.translate.Y;

       camera.position = camera.target + zAxis * camera.offset;

       camera.viewMatrix.M41 = -Vector3.Dot(xAxis, camera.position);
       camera.viewMatrix.M42 = -Vector3.Dot(yAxis, camera.position);
       camera.viewMatrix.M43 = -Vector3.Dot(zAxis, camera.position);

       Vector3.Negate(ref zAxis, out camera.viewDir);

       // Calculate the projection matrix.

       camera.projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
           (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 30000.0f);
   }
   ```

Second piece of code:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\DemoFont");

        GenerateTextures(2);

        // Load the assets for the Earth.
        earth.model = Content.Load<Model>(@"Models\earth");
        earth.effect = Content.Load<Effect>(@"Effects\earth");
        //earth.dayTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_day_color_spec");
        earth.dayTexture = colorTexture_;

        //earth.nightTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_night_color");
        //earth.nightTexture = heightTexture_;

        earth.cloudTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_clouds_alpha");

        //earth.normalMapTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_nrm");
        earth.normalMapTexture = normalTexture_;

        // Setup material settings for the Earth.
        earth.ambient = new Vector4(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        earth.diffuse = new Vector4(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        earth.specular = new Vector4(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        earth.shininess = 20.0f;
        earth.cloudStrength = 1.15f;

        // Calculate the bounding sphere of the Earth model and bind the
        // custom Earth effect file to the model.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in earth.model.Meshes)
        {
            earth.bounds = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(earth.bounds, mesh.BoundingSphere);

            foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
                part.Effect = earth.effect;
        }

        // Position the camera based on the Earth model's size.
        camera.target = earth.bounds.Center;
        camera.offset = earth.bounds.Radius * 3.0f;
        camera.orientation = Quaternion.Identity;

        // Setup starfield.
        starfieldComponent.Generate(5000, earth.bounds.Radius * 45.0f);



    }
```

And last:

```
private void DrawEarth()
    {
        Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateScale(0.2f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(earth.rotation) *
                           Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(-23.4f));

        foreach (ModelMesh m in earth.model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (Effect e in m.Effects)
            {
                if (hideClouds)
                {
                    e.CurrentTechnique = e.Techniques["EarthWithoutClouds"];
                }
                else
                {
                    e.CurrentTechnique = e.Techniques["EarthWithClouds"];
                    e.Parameters["cloudStrength"].SetValue(earth.cloudStrength);
                }

                e.Parameters["world"].SetValue(rotation);
                e.Parameters["view"].SetValue(camera.viewMatrix);
                e.Parameters["projection"].SetValue(camera.projectionMatrix);
                e.Parameters["cameraPos"].SetValue(new Vector4(camera.position, 1.0f));
                e.Parameters["globalAmbient"].SetValue(globalAmbient);
                e.Parameters["lightDir"].SetValue(sunlight.direction);
                e.Parameters["lightColor"].SetValue(sunlight.color);
                e.Parameters["materialAmbient"].SetValue(earth.ambient);
                e.Parameters["materialDiffuse"].SetValue(earth.diffuse);
                e.Parameters["materialSpecular"].SetValue(earth.specular);
                e.Parameters["materialShininess"].SetValue(earth.shininess);
                e.Parameters["landOceanColorGlossMap"].SetValue(earth.dayTexture);
                e.Parameters["cloudColorMap"].SetValue(earth.cloudTexture);
                e.Parameters["nightColorMap"].SetValue(earth.nightTexture);
                e.Parameters["normalMap"].SetValue(earth.normalMapTexture);

            }

            m.Draw();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like culling, one of the vertices is culled so the whole triangle is

Comment: @Sayse: backface culling is performed per face. A single vertex is neither culled nor not culled.
TO, Could you explain at least the concept of drawing the planet (what is drawn in which order and what states are set?). What do you expect of the second image? If you want the planet to disappear, you should post the rendering code.

Comment: Do you know a way to fix it or at least check if its the real problem? 
I have this line that was supposed to fix this issue but didnt.

GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;

Comment: @Nico Schertler that looks to be exactly what.is happening, you could make the far plane and near plane values really far away, the only other thing it could be is the normals being negative

Comment: To test that you can change your light direction

Comment: As you can see i was playing around with this and no matter what values i use, it doesnt help. However, setting the far plane value to quite low one makes clouds disappear. Also i will try changing direction of light.


camera.projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
        (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 30000.0f);

Comment: Could you add the shader code? How often is the `foreach (Effect e in m.Effects)` loop performed? So, how many effects are there in the  mesh?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K4nayPcx

http://pastebin.com/3aVfJQEs

Here is all relevant code. I tried to comment it to make it understandable.

Also im uploading the whole project to Dropbox (5mb)

Comment: And the last thing is whole project. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/819242/Procedural%20edited.zip

I would like to thank for all the help i have received already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed caused by the textures.

I guess you (or someone else) swapped some lines in `LoadContent`. Here are the correct ones:

```
earth.dayTexture =
    Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_day_color_spec"); // <-- correct
//earth.dayTexture = colorTexture_; <-- wrong

earth.nightTexture = 
    Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_night_color"); // <-- correct
//earth.nightTexture = heightTexture_; <-- wrong

earth.normalMapTexture = 
    Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\earth_nrm"); // <-- correct
//earth.normalMapTexture = normalTexture_; <-- wrong
```

The other  textures were procedurally generated. Those algorithms probably don't work. I haven't had a look at them though.